# Flutter Speech recognition Navigate to next sacreen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am implementing the speech_text recognition feature in my flutter app which I have done successfully my problem is that I want to perform a task when user finish up their speech it goes to the next screen after finishing speech any expert is here who can help me  here is my code below

```
   void _listen() async {
      if (!islistening) {
        bool available = await speechToText.initialize(
          onStatus: (val) => print('onStatus: $val'),
          onError: (val) => print('onError: $val'),
        );
        if (available) {
          setState(() {
            islistening = true;
          });
          speechToText.listen(
              onResult: (result) =>
                  setState(() {
                    text = result.recognizedWords;
                    if (_dialogKey.currentState != null && _dialogKey.currentState!.mounted) {
                      _dialogKey.currentState!.setState(() {
                        text =result.recognizedWords;

                      });



                    }

                    print(result.recognizedWords);
              

                  })
          );
        }
      } else {
        setState(() => islistening = false

        );
        speechToText.stop();
      }
    }
```

Comment: @GoldenLion i am using speech_to_text: ^5.5.0 for speech recognition

Comment: @GoldenLion so what solution for it?

Comment: @GoldenLion bro i am developing it for ios and android i perform this task in native android but on flutter its very anoying

Comment: speech_recognition: "^0.3.0"  try this.  it seems like others have been using it

Answer (score 0):

run the code and in your debug console see what the OnError message is.

I am getting the error: onError: SpeechRecognitionError msg: no-speech, permanent: false

the error relates to ChromeProxyService
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45380

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_error.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_result.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart' as stt;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late stt.SpeechToText _speechToText;
  bool _speechEnabled = false;
  String _lastWords = '';
  bool _isListening=false;
  double _confidence=1.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     _speechToText= stt.SpeechToText();
     setState(() {
       _isListening=false;
     });
    
  }

  /// This has to happen only once per app
  //void _initSpeech() async {
  //  _speechEnabled = await _speechToText.initialize();
  //  setState(() {});
  //}

  /// Each time to start a speech recognition session
_listen() async {
    if (!_isListening)
    {
      print("reached");
       _speechEnabled = await _speechToText.initialize(
         onStatus: (val)=>print('onStatus: $val'),
         onError: (val)=>print('onError: $val'),
       );
       if (_speechEnabled)
       {
         setState(() {
           _isListening=true;
         });

       }
    
     _speechToText.listen(onResult:(val)=>setState((){
        _lastWords = val.recognizedWords;
        if(val.hasConfidenceRating && val.confidence>0)
        {
          _confidence=val.confidence;
        }
     }));
    }
    else{
      setState(()=>_isListening=false);
      _speechToText.stop();
    }
    //setState(() {});
  }

  /// Manually stop the active speech recognition session
  /// Note that there are also timeouts that each platform enforces
  /// and the SpeechToText plugin supports setting timeouts on the
  /// listen method.
  //void _stopListening() async {
  //  await _speechToText.stop();
  //  setState(() {});
  //}

  /// This is the callback that the SpeechToText plugin calls when
  /// the platform returns recognized words.
  void _onSpeechResult(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
    setState(() {
      _lastWords = result.recognizedWords;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Speech Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Text(
                'Recognized words:',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Text(
                  // If listening is active show the recognized words
                  _speechToText.isListening
                      ? '$_lastWords'
                      // If listening isn't active but could be tell the user
                      // how to start it, otherwise indicate that speech
                      // recognition is not yet ready or not supported on
                      // the target device
                      : _speechEnabled
                          ? 'Tap the microphone to start listening...'
                          : 'Speech not available',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed:() async {await _listen();},
        tooltip: 'Listen',
        child: Icon(_isListening? Icons.mic_off : Icons.mic),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: which version you are using

Comment: add your action in the onResult event.

Comment: how to add this event?

Comment: create a model class.  set values in the model class from the onresult.  use the values of the model when building the scaffold to determine the widget to render.  similar technique is used when render on a bottombar navigate button.